# What is a word or a phrase that means "interactive and amusing stuff?"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am redesigning my website to have fewer categories, but I am running into problems with the "Games" category. I have a few things that are interactive, and fun, but not necessarily games. For example, a fireworks simulator.

I am trying to find a word that means "fun interactive stuff," or "games and other amusement." It needs to be fairly short, because it needs to fit in one of my tabs, so it can't be more than 15-20 letters or so.

I was thinking about "interactivity," but that doesn't really capture what the category is about (interactive and *fun* stuff).

Just "fun" might work, but I think it's too vague. Music, video, etc. can be fun, too.

A phrase would work too, as long it's not *too* long.

Comment: Umm... I'll chime in with a coinage I don't think was used before. I'll add an answer if you like it. It's "nut apps". See? Nuts can be appetizers and they have numerous kinds for different occasions; they can be couch diversions or a good match for some desserts. You get the idea.

Comment: @Mussri But you have to explain it so there's no point in thinking of a short phrase if you have to type 10x more characters to explain it :P

Comment: ‘Nut apps’ would be very strange to me. I would assume it was a section full of smartphone applications all dedicated to nuts, or perhaps of crazy smartphone applications.

Comment: Quirky Games Corner

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Fun* on its own works fine for me—I would also categorise music and videos under it, but I would not *expect* to find music or videos on a website where a menu item is labelled ‘fun’. I would expect to find more or less interactive, amusing things, like games, jokes, cartoon strips, etc.

To add to the interactive dimension and more or less exclude music and video, perhaps ***fun and games*** could be used. That is a more or less set phrase that does not merely refer to anything that is fun + anything that is games, but rather (dictionary definition) to “amusing and enjoyable activities”.

Of course, it’s hard to tell if this is ideal for you without seeing what the rest of your site looks like; but it works well in general, I’d say.

Comment: Ooh, "fun and games" sounds good. That's the kind of thing I was looking for. +1

Answer (score 3):

The word [*diversions*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/diversion) ("activities you do for fun" per the link) should cover it.

Comment: Yes, but its primary use is "distraction" or "taking attention away," which does not really describe this. At least that's what I think of when I hear that word.

Comment: I think you're thinking of the word too narrowly; I think of "fun stuff" or "stuff to while away the time" my when I hear _diversions_.

Comment: Hmm, maybe, but it still isn't really immediately obvious to me, which is important for a website.

Comment: It should be immediately obvious to almost any native English speaker. Who is your target audience?

Comment: Mostly native English speakers, but I am one and I still think it requires a bit more thinking. I personally automatically think "distraction" when I hear "diversion," and I need people to immediately understand what the category is supposed to be about.

Comment: My grandmother's house was full of books like [_The Ultimate Book of Puzzles, Diversions, and Brainteasers_](http://www.ebook3000.com/The-Ultimate-Book-of-Puzzles--Mathematical-Diversions--and-Brainteasers--A-Definitive-Collection-of-the-Best-Puzzles_84996.html), many of which had _diversion_ in the title. I guess that's why _diversion_ has that association for me.

Comment: Well, in that context, it's easy to figure out that it's using your meaning, because of the words surrounding it.

Answer (score 2):

The word **toys** is sometimes used in that context -- I've seen it used to talk simulations that are not very game like.  ([Here](http://www.ludology.org/articles/ludology.htm), for instance.)

**Games & Toys** would probably capture your meaning most clearly, but obviously is more than a single word.

Answer (score 2):

- **Fun Activities**
- **Recreation** (with or without the word: *activities*)
- **Favourite pastimes** This would cover music, videos, games etc..
- **Hobbies & Interests**
- **Escapades** Which is stretching it a bit, but it is one word and users would easily understand what the tab meant. The dictionary definition of *a wild exciting adventure* is positive to boot.

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy to borrow a word from another language you might consider [divertissement](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/divertissement).

Its specific meaning relates to the theatre as *a brief entertainment or diversion, usually between the acts of a play* [[Collins](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/divertissement)] but it can be used more generally for any short, interesting or amusing entertainment.

Comment: If this were not also an English word, I'd have to downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Previously-mentioned *diversions* is a good suggestion, but consider also some of its synonyms, including *[pastimes](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pastime#English)* and 
*[amusements](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/amusement#Noun)*, which respectively refer to “That which amuses, and serves to make time pass agreeably; sport; amusement; diversion; games” and  “activity that is entertaining or amusing”.

Answer (score 0):

Engaging

The Error prompt says I have to enter 30 characters or more so I will tell you how I got here. I looked up "a word for fun and interactive" on google and clicked the 4th link. In an attempt to answer your question and be helpful, I answered my own.

Comment: Hi A_mai, welcome to ELU! You could provide a definition of the word you're proposing, instead of telling us you need to meet a certain character limit, which is not at all related to the matter at hand. Here we require answers to contain some information to back them up.

Comment: ... Yes; the lower word limit is to encourage answers with reasonable substance, containing supporting linked attributed references and sound arguments, rather than off-topic workarounds.